# Data manipulation and conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I have eight text boxes each can have any numerical value only consisting of the numbers 1-8 up to eight digits each. No 0's or 9's.

I am using a timer to loop through the sequences of text boxes at a given rate. This is already configured.

Now here's the hard part.

I need to output the first value of a text box, wait some time then output it's counter *letter* (below the number on the keyboard), go to the next text box and repeat. Example:

I have in my eight boxes:

```
1
34
765
2
56
84
7
12345678
```

After each output of each consecutive text box I need to output:

```
Q
ER
UYT
W
TY
IR
U
QWERTYUI
```

The "output" is going to be `SerialPort1.Write(*numbers or letters*)` separated by a timer tick between each ON/OFF. Numbers turn the device on, letters turn it off. Starting with `SerialPort1.Write(TxtLoop1.Text)`

I already have the RS-232 communications set up. The information is going to a DLP-IO8 USB 8-channel data acquisition board.

To better understand the device:

1-8 turns ON each channel (12345678)

Q-I turns OFF each channel (QWERTYUI)

Truth table for device:

```
1 = Ch1 ON | Q = Ch1 OFF
2 = Ch2 ON | W = Ch2 OFF
3 = Ch3 ON | E = Ch3 OFF
--
8 = Ch8 ON | I = Ch8 OFF
```

Sending a "124" will turn on channels 1, 2 and 4.
Sending a "QWR" will turn off channels 1, 2 and 4.

I've only been coding for a few days now so go easy. Learning as I go.
My [form](http://i81.photobucket.com/albums/j230/sparky3489/PC%20interface/Form.png) for reference

Ultimately I'm trying bring my [PC Interface project](http://sparky3489.webs.com/pcinterfaceproject.htm) up to date by going from a parallel port to USB. This will be the "Custom Loop" function for the device.

```
Dim loopnum1 As String
        loopnum1 = TxtLoop1.Text
        Dim ListOfloop1 As String() = loopnum1.Split(New Char() {""})
        Dim singlenum1 As String
        Dim offloop1 As String
        offloop1 = "Q"
        For Each singlenum1 In ListOfloop1
            SerialPort1.Write(singlenum1)
            Timer2.Interval = (cmbSPLoop.Value) * 12
            If singlenum1 = "1" Then offloop1 = "Q"
            If singlenum1 = "2" Then offloop1 = "W"
            If singlenum1 = "3" Then offloop1 = "E"
            If singlenum1 = "4" Then offloop1 = "R"
            If singlenum1 = "5" Then offloop1 = "T"
            If singlenum1 = "6" Then offloop1 = "Y"
            If singlenum1 = "7" Then offloop1 = "U"
            If singlenum1 = "8" Then offloop1 = "I"
            SerialPort1.Write(offloop1)
        Next
        Dim loopnum2 As String
        loopnum2 = TxtLoop2.Text
        Dim ListOfloop2 As String() = loopnum2.Split(New Char() {""})
        Dim singlenum2 As String
        Dim offloop2 As String
        offloop2 = "Q"
        For Each singlenum2 In ListOfloop2
            SerialPort1.Write(singlenum2)
            Timer2.Interval = (cmbSPLoop.Value) * 12
            If singlenum2 = "1" Then offloop2 = "Q"
            If singlenum2 = "2" Then offloop2 = "W"
            If singlenum2 = "3" Then offloop2 = "E"
            If singlenum2 = "4" Then offloop2 = "R"
            If singlenum2 = "5" Then offloop2 = "T"
            If singlenum2 = "6" Then offloop2 = "Y"
            If singlenum2 = "7" Then offloop2 = "U"
            If singlenum2 = "8" Then offloop2 = "I"
            SerialPort1.Write(offloop2)
        Next
```

etc.

I guess I either do this eight times in a row once with each increment of TxtLoop#.text or?

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. Is there a specific problem your having, or are you looking for general advice on how to implement this?

Comment: It's a great project. I think the asker wants to know how to playback the sequence of numbers and letters and send them to the serial port.

Comment: @BrianWillis Mpelletier has the idea. This is a very rough idea of the code. I might be totally off.

Comment: Here's the link for the DLP-IO8 - http://www.dlpdesign.com/usb/io8.shtml

Comment: How'd you go with this Scott?

Comment: I can't believe Jeremy's answer only has 1 upvote. i know ports is soemwhat esoteric but seriously you guys should give credit. BTW how come Sparky2489 hasn't marked the ANSWER? srsly not cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I either do this eight times in a row once with each increment of TxtLoop#.text or ?`

I think you want to try out a nested loop, rather than 8 loops that output *each character in* the 8 textboxes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OutputToSerialPort()
    End Sub


Private Sub OutputToSerialPort()
    Dim txt = New TextBox
    For index As Integer = 1 To 8
        txt = FindControl(GroupBox1.Controls, "TextBox" & index)
        Dim ListOfloop As Char() = txt.Text.ToCharArray()  '<- edits on this line
        Dim singlenum As String
        Dim offloop As String
        offloop = "Q"
        For Each singlenum In ListOfloop
            'SerialPort1.Write(singlenum)
            'Timer2.Interval = (cmbSPLoop.Value) * 12
            If singlenum = "1" Then offloop = "Q"
            If singlenum = "2" Then offloop = "W"
            If singlenum = "3" Then offloop = "E"
            If singlenum = "4" Then offloop = "R"
            If singlenum = "5" Then offloop = "T"
            If singlenum = "6" Then offloop = "Y"
            If singlenum = "7" Then offloop = "U"
            If singlenum = "8" Then offloop = "I"
            'SerialPort1.Write(offloop)
        Next
    Next index
End Sub

Public Function FindControl(ByVal oControls As Control.ControlCollection,
ByVal strControlName As String) As Control
    Dim MyCtl As Control

    For Each MyCtl In oControls
        If MyCtl.Name = strControlName Then
            Return MyCtl
        Else
            If MyCtl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                Return FindControl(MyCtl.Controls, strControlName)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

ps I dont think you need loopnum1.Split (or in my code that is .Split(New Char() {""}) its not turning multiple digits into an array, thats why the italics. **We discussed this and you let me know you did want to output each digit, in each textbox and I have edited my answer.**

Comment: I have a Start/Stop button for the custom loop so I need a delay for speed control which is controlled by Timer2.Interval = (cmbSPLoop.Value) * 12

Comment: cmbSPLoop goes from 1 to 10. I have the delay at 12 because I thought I'd have to repeat steps.

Comment: I should have clarified: I just commented out the lines of code with the timer and the serial output so it would compile (in my IDE). Please uncomment those lines and just forget about that button click

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Dim ListOfloop As String() = txt.Text.Split(New Char() {""})

Comment: Make sure your GroupBox is named GroupBox1 and make sure Textboxes are named TextBox1, TextBox2 & etc. Also lets get you debugging, instead of pressing F5 to start the app, press F11 to step through code and F10 to step over functions (rather than drilling into them)

Comment: It's much faster to change the line than my form - txt = FindControl(GroupBox3.Controls, "TxtLoop" & index)

Comment: OutputToSerialPort() doesn't send any data to my COM port. I use SerialPort1.Write(_variable_)

Comment: whats the error? - ok I see the bit in italics waas relevant. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: each text box can contain more than one number.

Comment: Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Write' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: Far right side - http://i81.photobucket.com/albums/j230/sparky3489/PC%20interface/Form.png

Comment: If you copy my code you wont get the error. I guess by the error message the problem is that your passing more than one parameter to the SerialPort1.Write method. ps that pic is the same one in your question.

Comment: So what do I put in place of OutputToSerialPort()?  If I try to use SerialPort1.Write() I get an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6874/discussion-between-sparky3489-and-jeremy-thompson)

Comment: *EDIT*



WooHoo!!! I finally got it! My project is now 100% complete!



Thanks again to all!!!

Comment: @sparky3489 - there is a holo tickbox next to each answer, you'll receive a couple points for marking answers. Thanks

Comment: Revisiting this as you do occasionally visit this site. Care to accept?